# site-description css is overriden

Tags: css, headers, theme-twenty-thirteen

I'm trying to change the site-description color of my twentythirteen header to #220E10.

My style.css file reads :

```
.site-description {
    font: 300 italic 20px "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #220E10;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

However, the color of my header (viewable [here](http://femmes.jeunes-democrates.org)) remains #FF6000.

I know the css file is the used as a source for size, font and other details, since I can effectively change those and see the results happen. The color will not change however.

I suspect the override has something to do with the basic Wordpress editor which allows you to change the color of your header text.

I can't seem to be able to identify the location of the source css being used for this color. The #FF6000 color is not present in my style.css file, except for that intentional navbar.

Could you help me edit the site-description to a different color ?

Comment: I am sure it is [css specificity](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+specificity)

Comment: I imagine so, @s_ha_dum, but I do not know where this more specific code resides. It do not believe it is in the style.css file.

Comment: You just need to make _your_ code more specific. You can do that without ever knowing what the other code is, but this is not a WordPress question, really. It is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks to your input I was able to identify a fix with `!important`.

Comment: the color is set from within ***dashboard - appearance - header - header text - text color***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a CSS rule being output in the `<head>` of that document that is defining the color, *after* your stylesheet is included (thus overriding it). Take a look at the options for the theme, and see if there's a way to set the color through the admin area.

If you want to override JUST the description, add `!important` to the color rule in your css file. It's an unfortunate solution, since `!important` rules can cause all kinds of havoc during maintenance phases... but the other option is to dig into the theme files and try to change the options settings to two color settings, or change the output in the theme header so it only defines a color for the title, instead of both the title and description.

Comment: There is, but it covers both site-title and site-description. I believe this is causing the override, but I'm not sure how to counter it.

Comment: If you want to override JUST the description, add `!important` to the color rule in your css file. It's an unfortunate solution, since `!important` rules can cause all kinds of havoc during maintenance phases... but the other option is to dig into the theme files and try to change the options settings to two color settings.

Comment: This does work indeed. Would you like to edit your answer with the information from your comment so I can upvote it ? Will also have a look at the theme files, as per your suggestion.

Comment: Read up on [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to learn more about how to override the settings without using `!important`.